# Cakephp 3 Imagine plugin doesn't work on hosting server

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, hosting

I have a lot of problems with configure my app in hosting server. On my localmachine all it's great. 
First, app doesn't see plugin so i must change first letters on folders to uppercase. imagine => Imagine, lib => Lib

But now when I try upolad a file a got this:

Error: Class 'Imagine\Image\AbstractImagine' not found 
File /home/../../../public_html/../vendor/Imagine/Imagine/Lib/Imagine/Gd/Imagine.php 
Line: 28

But AbstractImagine.php is in Image folder so I have no idea how to solve this. Help!!!

Comment: At a guess, since you haven't shown anything specific, you are using windows and have many more case errors in your file/folder names. Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: I mean AbstractImagine.php ofcourse, corected thx, So you think its all OS problems?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, after you clarify the question (showing relevant paths, your code, full error messages) I might.